# Hyper-V apply snapshot without taking current snapshot?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

In Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012, how can I apply a snapshot without automatically taking a snapshot of the current state? I think there was a prompt asking whether to take a snapshot or not before applying the target snapshot, I must've clicked “yes, save this option from now on”. However I can’t find a way to change that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hyper-V Manager:

1. Right-click on the server's name in the left pane and select "Hyper-v Settings..."
2. Click "Reset Check Boxes"
3. Click "Reset"